# Liquid from AzureLogicApps parsing an object dynamically

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm looking to parse a JSON object dynamically in a Liquid.
So far my efforts have been in vain as you can't loop over an object with a regular for loop.
The amount of properties in the ticket_attributes objects is dynamic and can vary in keynames.

Input object:

```
{
  "action": "insert",
  "state": "New",
  "ticket_attributes": {
    "category": "Event",
    "user_name": "Customer  ",
"prop3":"data1",
"prop4":"data1",
  },
  "ticket_number": "INC9190433"
}
```

Liquid snippets used that don't work:

```
{% for prop in content.ticket_attributes %}
  {{prop[0]}}:{{prop[1]}}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in content.ticket_attributes %}
{{ forloop.index }}: {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any pointers on how to solve this inside the template?

Comment: Hi Frolos, could you please provide a sample with the original data format and the format of the data what you expect ?

Comment: The original data that i need to parse is mentioned in the input object. I want to parse   "ticket_attributes": {
    "category": "Event",
    "user_name": "Customer  ",
"prop3":"data1",
"prop4":"data1",
  }  and output the inidivual properties in an object like so: {
    "category": "Event",
    "user_name": "Customer  ",
"prop3":"data1",
"prop4":"data1",
  }

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, it seems liquid in azure logic app doesn't support loop hash. I think we can implement this requirement outside azure logic app with liquid as the template you provide in your question, but in azure logic app we can't.

For this requirement, I think we can just parse the json data, get the property `ticket_attributes` as string, remove the head `"ticket_attributes": {` and the tail `},` and then insert it back to the resource json data.